# XPC Service returning NSAttributtedString

Tags: cocoa, xpc

I have a huge problem to transfer NSAttributtedString in a block callback from XPC service.

I am trying to return basic string as:

```
NSDictionary *arrayComa = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor colorWithRGB:0xD35250],
                            NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Monaco" size:11]};

NSMutableAttributedString *testString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"{}" attributes:arrayComa];
```

I have also whitelisted the incoming response as:

```
 let incommingClasses:Set = Set(arrayLiteral: [NSMutableAttributedString.self, NSAttributedString.self, NSColor.self, NSFont.self, NSString.self, ])
 connectionService.remoteObjectInterface?.setClasses(incommingClasses, forSelector: attributtedText:withReply:, argumentIndex: 0, ofReply: true)
```

What ever I do I get Errors:

```
Exception caught during decoding of received reply to message     'Exception caught during decoding of received reply to message 'attributtedText:withReply':, dropping incoming message and calling failure block.

Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#1 of invocation):
<NSInvocation: 0x6000006649c0>
return value: {v} void
target: {@?} 0x0 (block)
argument 1: {@"NSMutableAttributedString"} 0x0    

Exception: value for key '<no key>' was of unexpected class 'NSMutableAttributedString'. Allowed classes are '{(
    (
    NSMutableAttributedString,
    NSAttributedString,
    NSColor,
    NSFont,
    NSString
)
```

)}'.

Anybody has transferred NSAttributtedText via XPC Service succesfully?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I got a reply to my message on devforums, a workaround is to use an NSSet and to cast it as Set when passing to to setClasses(). Another issue is that there already are pre-set classes for all selectors, and therefore you need to add your own to the current ones, rather than set yours only. Here's a working code :

```
        let interface = NSXPCInterface(withProtocol: MyProtocol.self)

    let expectedClasses = NSSet.setWithArray([[NSMutableAttributedString.self, NSAttributedString.self, NSColor.self, NSFont.self])
    let currentExpectedClasses = interface.classesForSelector("attributtedText:withReply:", argumentIndex: 0, ofReply: false) as NSSet

    let allClasses = currentExpectedClasses.setByAddingSet(expectedClasses)

    interface.setClasses(allClasses as Set<NSObject>, forSelector: "attributtedText:withReply:", argumentIndex: 0, ofReply: false)
```

Original answer :

This will only be a partial answer as I haven't found the right way to do this either yet, but

```
let incommingClasses:Set = Set(arrayLiteral: [NSMutableAttributedString.self, NSAttributedString.self, NSColor.self, NSFont.self, NSString.self, ])
```

returns a Set<NSArray>, which is not what you want. I assume you added the 'arrayLiteral' argument label because the compiler told you so, however this compiles :

```
let foo = Set(["string1", "string2"])
```

and it returns a Set<String>.

The problem is that I couldn't find a way to create a Set of class types. I've asked on Apple's devforums : https://devforums.apple.com/thread/271316 but unless I'm missing something obvious, this looks like an API bug.